# Output from for cycle loop to variable and then export to HTML

Tags: powershell

I have this PowerShell code for comparing the data flow across the switch when the NewData and CompareData data is the same, the port is inactive. If different, it is active. It used for a monthly message. I have a problem with the output of the loop. I want to store all the passages into a variable that I can then export to HTML.

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt $NewData.Length; $i++){
if($NewData[$i] -eq $CompareData[$i]){
$n = $i
$n++
Write-Host "Port $n   Unactive"  -ForegroundColor Yellow 
}
elseif($NovaData[$i] -ne $SrovavaciData[$i]){
$a = $i
$a++
Write-Host "Port $a   Active"  -ForegroundColor Green
}
}
```

This is my output that I need to get into the variable. So far I can save only last item.

```
Port 2   Unactive
Port 7   Unactive
Port 8   Unactive
Port 12   Unactive
Port 13   Unactive
Port 14   Unactive
Port 15   Unactive
Port 18   Unactive
Port 21   Unactive
Port 23   Unactive
Port 25   Unactive
Port 26   Unactive
Port 29   Unactive
Port 30   Unactive
Port 33   Unactive
Port 36   Unactive
Port 38   Unactive
Port 46   Unactive
Port 47   Unactive
```

Thanks for the anwers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just store the each line you want to write into an array.

```
$informations = @()
for ($i=0; $i -lt $NewData.Length; $i++) {
    if($NewData[$i] -eq $CompareData[$i]) {
        $message = "Port $($i +1) Unactive"
        Write-Host $Message -ForegroundColor Yellow

    elseif($NovaData[$i] -ne $SrovavaciData[$i]) {
        $message = "Port $($i +1) Active"
        Write-Host $Message -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
    $informations += $message
}
```

A **better** way would be to store both values in a hash-list and export the whole thing to html later like this:

```
$informations = @{}
for ($i=0; $i -lt $NewData.Length; $i++) {
    if($NewData[$i] -eq $CompareData[$i]) {
        $informations += @{"Port $($i +1)"="Unactive}

    elseif($NovaData[$i] -ne $SrovavaciData[$i]) {
        $informations += @{"Port $($i +1)"="Active}
    }
}

New-Object psobject -Property $informations | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment | Out-File .\port-report.html
```

This will generate a table off all your results in the html file.

Comment: Now I generate the HTML file, but I have a format problem, the resulting output is generated behind me and not under the column. (Inactive Port 2 Inactive Port 7 Inactive Port 8)

Answer (score 0):

Store everything in an array:

```
$output = @()
for ($i=0; $i -lt $NewData.Length; $i++){
    if($NewData[$i] -eq $CompareData[$i]){
        $n = $i
        $n++
        $output += "Port $n   Unactive"
    }
    elseif($NovaData[$i] -ne $SrovavaciData[$i]){
        $a = $i
        $a++
        $output += "Port $a   Active"
    }
}

$output
```

Side note: if there are a lot of items to be stored in the array list, adding new elements using += is pretty slow since every time you add an element the whole array gets copied and the new item added.